# g77 compiling errors (cannot find crt1.o, crti.o, -lgcc_s)

Tags: linux, fortran, ubuntu-14.04, g77

I really need some help. I'm trying to compile and execute some programs for my Thesis.

The problem is, I never used Fortran before, so I'm blindly relying on the documentation....it said to use a few commmands to do the work, specifically

```
setenv bc03 PATH TO SRC DIRECTORY
cd $bc03
source ./.bc_cshrc
```

So, i Installed Ubuntu 14.04 (I was working on Windows, which is another issue, I'm new to Linux too), and used these commands in the terminal.

At first it didn't work 'cause it couldn't recognize the g77 command, I followed a tutorial to install g77, launched the "make all" command again, and it seems it partially works.
As I get it, the compiler creates a bunch of .o files in the directory, but when it comes to compile the 6 main programs

```
"make bin_ised ascii_ised vel_disp csp_galaxev add_bursts downgrade_resolution"
```

it gives me these errors (I translated some parts from Italian)

```
make[1]: entering directory "/home/lews/Documenti/bc03/src"
g77 -ffixed-line-length-132 bin_ised.f ./public_utilities.a -o bin_ised
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crt1.o: File o directory non esistente
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crti.o: File o directory non esistente
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [bin_ised] Errore 1
make[1]: leaving directory "/home/lews/Documenti/bc03/src"
make: *** [all] Errore 2
```

I'm kind lost here, as I told you I'm new to both Fortran and Linux, so I really can't figure it out....thanks for the help!

Comment: It's difficult to tell because it depends on the installation. If you do `ls /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` (or something similar, if this directory doesn't exist), does it list `crt1.o`, `crti.o` and `libgcc_s.*`? If yes,  doing `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` before `make` might sort it out.

Comment: In the directory there are the crt1.o and the crti.o files, the other one is missing.

I tried to use your command anyway, but it does not work...I forgot to say that before doing anything, I'm using the command "tcsh" because the commands I'm supposed to use to compile the files are in csh syntax, so I guess I should change a bit the syntax of the command you suggested

Answer (score 1):

Ditch g77.  It has been unsupported for years and, quite apparently, is not correctly configured on your system (libraries missing).

Use gfortran instead, which comes with all major Linux installations. gfortran is compatible with g77, wich a few very minor exceptions.

If your build script explicitly mentions g77, replace that by gfortran, and adjust the other flags if necessary.

I think gfortran-4.9 is the current Ubuntu package.